# grails LazyInitializationException in transactional service

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a problem. I have  service that is transactional  in grails :

```
class MyService {

   static transactional = true

   Set<Furniture> getFurniture(Long idHouse) {
      return MyHouse.get(idHouse).getFurniture()
   }
}
```

In my controller I have : `def myService` and I call `myService.getFurniture(id)`

Even though my service is transactional I get : `LazyInitializationException`
I am using Grails 2.0.0.RC3
Thx.

Answer (score 2):

While you're in the transaction there is an open session the whole time and lazy-loaded collections will be able to resolve when referenced. But you're just returning the uninitialized collection, and once it's returned to the controller it is disconnected from the Hibernate session that loaded it.

So you just need to initialize the collection and there are a couple of options. One is to call the `size()` method:

```
Set<Furniture> getFurniture(Long idHouse) {
   def furniture = MyHouse.get(idHouse).furniture
   furniture.size() // force eager init
   furniture
}
```

This will force Hibernate to go the database and populate the collection. This relies on a side effect though - the best way is to call `Hibernate.initialize()`:

```
import org.hibernate.Hibernate
...

Set<Furniture> getFurniture(Long idHouse) {
   def furniture = MyHouse.get(idHouse).furniture
   Hibernate.initialize furniture
   furniture
}
```

Comment: Ok, but i am in the service witch is transactional. In a standard spring application, annotated with @TRansactional, if i am in the service and i do object.getFurniture() will go to the database and fetch my data. I don;t understand why in grails this is not posible. It is because i do MyHous.get ? an not MyHous mh = new MyHous(), mh.findBy.... ?

Comment: Perhaps in your other application you were eagerly loading the collection - Grails defaults to lazy loading. This is just standard Hibernate behavior since Grails services are very thin wrappers around standard Spring transactional services.

Comment: No, i have my relations lazy. In spring my session is closed when my transaction has ended. so my hibernate session is accessible through my transaction. It seems that in grails the hibernate session is closing earlier, and i don;t know how to configure grails to keep my hibernate session active until i close the transaction. My objects get detached even thought i am in a transaction. Is it possible with grails to have this behavior?

Comment: Hibernate.initialize thanks @BurtBeckwith. In my case it was a lazy object hanging off the main object so it was fixed by `Hibernate.initialize mainObject.subObject` after fetching main object

Answer (score 2):

Even if your service class is transactional, you may get lazy initialization exception. The transaction be closed when the service method finishes its execution. So you have detached objects on the controller side. It s not a grails issue.

On the House domain class

---

```
static mapping = {
    furniture lazy:false
}
```

---

This will provide that whenever you query a house, it will come with it's furniture

Or you can set the fetchmode of a specific query

---

```
def house = criteria.list{
    ...
    fetchMode('furniture', FetchMode.EAGER)
}
```

---